# Most appropriate test for my data?

Tags: anova, dataset, post-hoc

I am strugling with my current science project on how to determine statistical significance among my tested groups. I have however a very basic understanding of statistics and would like to understand it better in order to do my job well.

My case looks like this. I have results from experiments resulting in a % response (0-100). The subjects were split into 2 genders and 2 age categories, while the treatments were separated into 4 concentrations and 5 genotypes. Each observation has somewhere between 2 to 5 repeated measurements/replications. The response data do not appear to be normally distributed.

I have it all put into format but have no idea what kind of a test to run with so many variables. I understand that I should not do repeated tests, which is why I am looking for an overall solution. I wish to know all the differences within this set.

Comment: Try ANOVA. Maybe take the log of your Ys

Answer (score 2):

You could try anova. If your data has following columns:

```
subjectID
outcome
gender
agegrp
concgrp
genotype
```

You could run following R command for anova:

```
aov.out = aov(outcome ~ gender+agegrp+concgrp+genotype+Error(subjectID/concgrp), data=mydf)
```

Alternatively, you could try regression but it does not take into account repeated measurements:

```
summary(lm(outcome ~ gender+agegrp+concgrp+genotype+Error(subjectID/concgrp), data=mydf))
```

Best may be to use Box-Cox transformation to correct for non-normal data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box.E2.80.93Cox_transformation